# React App : Start API server with React server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, react-router

I'm working on a pretty simple [react](/questions/tagged/react) App (my first), but I can't figure out how to get both the API and the react server to start...

I'm using [react-router](/questions/tagged/react-router) for client routes and I've used [express](/questions/tagged/express) on another project so I've started my React project with it to setup the API.

**But I was wondering if there was a way to use [react-router](/questions/tagged/react-router) to handle API routes and return some data...**

I've googled and looked around but I can seem to find anything about that (nor confirming nor refuting).

Does anyone have any input about that?
(I know it isn't a proper SO question but I can't seem to find any info to close the nagging wonder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on a pretty simple react App (my first), but I can't
>   figure out how to get both the API and the react server to start...

There is an npm module that I use for my React/Express app called **concurrently** that I use to start my client and backend servers at the same time.

I installed that globally:

```
npm install concurrently
```

In my app's main `package.json`, I have the scripts setup like this:

```
"scripts":{
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  "server": "node bin/www",
  "client": "node start-client.js"
}
```

That setup allows me to run `npm start` and it starts up my server and client scripts.

In `start-client.js`, I have this:

```
const args = ["start"];
const opts = { stdio: "inherit", cwd: "client", shell: true };
require("child_process").spawn("npm", args, opts);
```

`start-client.js` is located at the root of my app.

My file structure looks like this:

```
|--bin
|--client
|--routes
|--app.js
|--package.json
|--start-client.js
```

> But I was wondering if there was a way to use react-router to handle
>   API routes and return some data...

To fetch data from the API server, I use the native `fetch()` method inside my React components.

Since I'm using Express, I will create a route and export it to my `app.js` file like so:

```
/* myRoute.js */
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('index', {title: 'Express'})
})

module.exports = router

/* app.js */

var myRoute = require('./routes/myRoute')
var app = express()
//will fetch data from this endpoint
app.use('/myRoute', myRoute)
```

Now in my React component, I will fetch data from `/myRoute` like so:

```
fetch('/myRoute')
  .then(res => JSON.parse(res))
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Thx for the input, I've almost understand everything, but one thing still any me : I guess `myRoute.js` is in `./routes/`, but what do you have in `./bin/` and `./bin/www/`? And to be sure, does `concurrently` also works in production?

Comment: And what about `build` `scripts` can we use `concurrently` too?

Comment: @R3uK `bin/www` starts up my node server. You probably call it `server.js`. I haven't used concurrently in production yet, but I don't see why it shouldn't work in production. You can read more about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to start both API server and react. In your express main file in my case `server.js`. You'd need to install `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware`.

```
// server.js
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import config from './webpack.config';

const app = express(),
  DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
  HTML_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html'),
  compiler = webpack(config),
  isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

if (isDevelopment) {
  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  }));

  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
} else {
  app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR));
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(HTML_FILE));
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.redirect(301, '/'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4200);
```

Then in your `webpack.config.js`, you can follow my settings below:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './app/app.jsx',
  ],
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    'react/addons': 'react',
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': 'react',
    'react/lib/ReactContext': 'react',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map',
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? undefined : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', './app/components'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /(\.js$|\.jsx$)/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'airbnb'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      minimize: true,
      compressor: {
        warnings: false,
      },
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Then in your `package.json` `scripts`:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "babel-node server.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon -e js --exec babel-node -- ./server.js",
    "test": "karma start"
  }
```

Now when you start your express server, your API and react will run together.

Comment: Thx for the input, that seems to handle both dev and prod start methods! But about `build` `script` does it work too? What do I have to define in `package.json`'s `scripts`? Thx in advance for the explanations!

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of the answer.